# dates as column header in json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I have a column with date as header see my `json` as below:

```
[{
  "Index": 1,
  "FirstName": "Jon",
  "LastName": "mind",
  "Job": "ME - preplaning",
  "3/8/2017": false,
  "3/7/2017": true
}, {
  "Index": 2,
  "FirstName": "KARIM",
  "LastName": "AL",
  "Job": "Mfg shift leader",
  "3/8/2017": false,
  "3/7/2017": false
}]
```

and I need to have  in my uigrid a checkbox for  dates columns in order to check if the value is true or false , 
so this is what i've done

```
 name: key, 
 displayName: key,
 type: 'boolean',
 cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.key">'
```

the variable key contains the column name , so key in my case will get `3/7/2017` , but it throws an error because i guess that `row.entity.3/7/2017` is not possible , any solution guys ?

Comment: `row.entity["3/7/2017"]` would be how you would "access" it in plain ol' javascript - not sure how you would translate that to angular though ... `row.entity[key]` perhaps

Comment: it didnt throw any error but i'm getting the checkbox unchecked , even that it has true value

Comment: and if i checked one , all the checkboxes in the same row get checked too

Comment: yeah, sorry, not sure how the checkboxes are "wired up" ...

Comment: I hope you know the **naming convention** which is very basics of any programming language

Comment: What is `row`? Sounds like you're only referring to one item in your array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you...

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{
        name: 'Index'
      }, {
        name: 'FirstName'
      }, {
        name: 'LastName'
      }, {
        name: 'Job'
      },
      {
        name: '3/8/2017',
        cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity[col.field]">'
      }, {
        name: '3/7/2017',
        cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity[col.field]">'
      }
    ],
    data: [{
      "Index": 1,
      "FirstName": "Jon",
      "LastName": "mind",
      "Job": "ME - preplaning",
      "3/8/2017": false,
      "3/7/2017": true
    }, {
      "Index": 2,
      "FirstName": "KARIM",
      "LastName": "AL",
      "Job": "Mfg shift leader",
      "3/8/2017": false,
      "3/7/2017": false
    }]
  };
}]);
```

```css
div[ui-grid] {
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.css" />
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
  <div>{{gridOptions.data}}</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.